# how to mount my d-link dns 323 NAS

Tags: 11.04, networking, mount

I have ubuntu 11.04 64bit.
I cant connect my dns 323 "NAS".
I only see the ip "169.254.6.199" on my router.
I use Nautilus "smb://169.254.6.199" and only see message "could not display "smb://169.254.6.199/".

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to me that your NAS is not receiving an IP address from your router.  169 is the private IP range given to devices so that they can directly connect and talk to each other without a dhcp server.  Your first step is going to be getting your NAS hooked up to your router and properly configured.